# Object of type data is not JSON serializable error in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a registration page that allows a user to sign up. After doing so, I want to call an API and then, save the data to my model (not saving it to a form though). I tried doing this:

**models.py:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name = 'profile')
    address = models.TextField()
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

**views.py:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and register_form.is_valid():
            username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
            first_name = user_form.cleaned_data.get('first_name'),
            last_name=user_form.cleaned_data.get('last_name'),
            email=user_form.cleaned_data.get('email'),
            password=user_form.cleaned_data.get('password2'),
            birthday = register_form.cleaned_data.get('dob'),
            address=register_form.cleaned_data.get('address'),
            payload = {'username': username,'first_name': first_name,'last_name': last_name,'email':email,'password':password,'register' : {'birthday': birthday,'address': address}}
            response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_api/',json=payload)
            return redirect("home") #re-direct if login is successful
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        register_form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'register_form': register_form})

class RegisterAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            content = {'status': 'You are registered'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from users.models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    birthday = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d")
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('birthday','address')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email', 'password', 'profile')

    def create(self, request, validated_data, *args, **kwargs):
        register_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)  
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            user.set_password(password)
        user.save()  
        Profile.objects.create(user = user, **register_data) 
        return validated_data
```

**However, I am getting this error:**

```
Object of type data is not JSON serializable error in Django
```

It seems that it's got to do with the birthday. On my template, a user can display the date of birth as 'YYYY-MM-DD'. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Show the full trace

Answer (score 1):

The `create` method in your `UserSerializer` should return a User instance instead of `validated_data`.

```py
def create(self, request, validated_data, *args, **kwargs):
   register_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
   password = validated_data.pop('password', None)  
   user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
   if password is not None:
       user.set_password(password)
   user.save()  
   Profile.objects.create(user = user, **register_data) 
   return user
```